# @font-face and Raphael VML textpath font-family

Tags: javascript, raphael, font-face

Does VML textpath support `@font-face` font-families? I'm trying to integrate this with Raphael, which uses Raphael VML textpaths for IE 7/8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tested and @font-face (using google web fonts) works in IE7-8.

Comment: Did you test it actually with VML textpaths?

Comment: so if you have a look at the code on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141008/how-to-display-vml-textpath-in-a-custom-font , font-face works for you in IE7-8? It doesn't work on my PC.. Custom font is in this case 'lucida_grande'.

Comment: take any font from google web fonts - http://www.google.com/fonts/ - for example, PT_sans, insert it to your page following google's instructions, then attach it to your SVG/VML container via CSS - "#svg-vml: {font-family: "PT_sans";}"

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Could you please have a look at http://product-designer.nl/ie8/test.html ? Please open it in IE 7/8. The top object doesn't show up in the right font, the bottom object does. Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried to use Cufon: http://product-designer.nl/ie8/test2.html, but also doesn't work. Can you think of a solution?

Comment: press F12 in IE, switch to "Console" and you'll see that your .woff and .ttf font files weren't accepted by IE.